# If $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

My text book says that

- If $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$, and if we define $(\frac{1}{f})(z_0) = 0$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$.

But I'm thinking that, since $f = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$ where $g(z)$ is analytic and nonzero at $z_0$, $\frac{1}{f}$, which equals $\frac{(z-z_0)^m}{g(z)}$, is surely analytic at $z_0$ and has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$. If it is analytic at $z_0$, then $z_0$ cannot be a singularity point.

Why does my text book say $z_0$ is a removable singularity and define $(\frac{1}{f})(z_0) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $\frac{1}{f}$ is only defined on a neighborhood of $z_0$ which excludes $z_0$ so you have to really define it. In fact, $\frac{1}{f}= \frac{(z-z_0)^m}{g(z)}$ does $\textbf{not}$ make sense at $z_0$.

Comment: Oh okay. Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We note that $z_0$ is not in the domain of $\frac{1}{f}$ since $f(z)$ is not *a priori* defined at $z_0$.  This situation may be remedied by *defining* $\frac{1}{f}(z_0)$ in a manner consistent with continuity, to wit:

We define

$\left (\dfrac{1}{f} \right )(z_0) = 0 \tag 1$

because

$\displaystyle \lim_{z \to z_0} \dfrac{(z - z_0)^m}{g(z)} = 0. \tag 2$

Comment: My real concern was why is $z_0$ not in the domain of $\frac{1}{f}$. But thank you!!

Comment: @YuqiaoHuang:  I added a few words.  Does that help?

Comment: Yep. Thank you!